# How to deal with ImmutableMultiDict

Tags: python

I'm trying to test my flask API with a `POST` request, but I have problems to deal with the ImmutableMultiDict.

The API:

```
@app.route("/df/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def get_df():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        select = request.form
```

request:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/df/ -d '{"ticker": "ETH-PERP"}'
```

`print(select)`:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('{"ticker": "ETH-PERP"}', '')])
```

How do I access the value ("ETH-PERP") ?

I tried:

```
select = request.form.getlist("ticker")
```

output: `[]`

```
select = request.form.to_dict(flat=True)
print(select[0])
```

output: `keyError: 0`

```
select = request.form.to_dict().values()[0]
```

output: `'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the request data is not a form, it's JSON.

You should probably use `request.json` to read it, which should give you a regular dictionary.